# Changing the resolution of my netbook to 1280x1024

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I have made a hack to my registry (Display1_DownScalingSupported) that allows you to have two new resolutions for your netbook (1024 x 768 and 1152 x 864).

However I would like to have 1280x1024 so that I will connect it with my monitor correctly.

What do you suggest me?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Connect a netbook to another monitor? or trying to display a desktop resolution that exceed the native resolution of your netbook?

Comment: Yes I would like to connect my netbook to another monitor. The monitor supports 1280x1024 something that my netbook does not allow it...

Comment: Duplicate question under different user name

Comment: I think this is the same username (come from serverfault), but account are not linked. BTW the question is flagged as duplicated, I guess moderators should make it definitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to hack on the registry to do that.
The display control panel (and your graphic card control panel eventually) should propose you to connect the external monitor in clone mode, use only this monitor, or extend your desktop to this monitor.

You may be able to do it with some kind of `FN+Fxx` key combination on some netbooks.

The clone mode may restrict you to the native resolution of the tiniest screen, but if you connect only the monitor you should be able to use its own native resolution instead.
If not, try to install the driver for your monitor.

Comment: You are my savor!!!!!

Comment: You welcome. If all is working, don't forget to vote up and turn question to solved.